# How to extract the first 2 numbers from ip

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have the text :

```
1.1.1.1
12.123.1.1
123.123.1.1
213.12.123.1
34.12.123
1.123.4.1
```

How can I extract to look like:

```
1.1
12.123
123.123
213.12
34.12
1.123
```

Comment: Where is your code so far? What did you tried?

Answer (score 3):

With `awk` it is as easy as using a field-separator of `'.'` (e.g. `awk -F.`) and printing the first two fields separated by a `'.'` which can be accomplished with `printf` or by setting `OFS=.`, e.g. with:

```
awk -F. '{printf "%d.%d\n", $1, $2}' file
```

or

```
awk -F. -v OFS=. '{print $1, $2}' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your input in `file`, e.g.

```
$ awk -F. -v OFS=. '{print $1, $2}' file
1.1
12.123
123.123
213.12
34.12
1.123
```

**Using `sed`**

You can handle this quite easily with `sed`, for example:

```
$ sed -r 's/([0-9]+[.][0-9]+).*$/\1/' file
1.1
12.123
123.123
213.12
34.12
1.123
```

Where you simply use an extended regular expression, to capture the first set of digits (octet) the dot and the second octet and then reinsert that information as a back-reference.

If you are limited to basic regular expressions for some reason, then you can use:

```
sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]*[.][0-9][0-9]*\).*$/\1/' file
```

Same result. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is in file `text`, do this:

```
cut -d'.' -f1,2 <text
```

It says "cut each line into 'fields' each separated by a so-called delimiter  '.', and then output fields 1 and 2".

Answer (score 2):

Short `awk` that works if all line are at the same format.

```
awk -F. '$0=$1FS$2' file
1.1
12.123
123.123
213.12
34.12
1.123
```